# java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400> for Spring Boot Rest Controller Patch request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

Below is my controller (SalesOrderController.Java) and JUnit Test (SalesOrderControllerTest.Java)

```
@RestController
```

public class SalesOrderController extends BaseController {

```
/** The Constant LOGGER. */
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SalesOrderController.class);

/** The sales order service. */
@Autowired
private ISalesOrderService salesOrderService;

@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(value = "/issuers/{issuerId}/reassign-sales-orders", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public BaseResponse reassignSalesOrder(@PathVariable("issuerId") final Long pIssuerId,
        @RequestBody @Valid final ReassignSalesOrderRequest pReassignSalesOrderRequest) {
    LOGGER.info("Reassigning sales orders of issuer:" + pIssuerId);
    return salesOrderService.reassignSalesOrder(pIssuerId, pReassignSalesOrderRequest);
}
```

}

and below is my Junit for above controller

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

public class SalesOrderControllerTest extends AbstractBaseControllerTest {

```
/** The sales order service. */
@Mock
private ISalesOrderService salesOrderService;

/** The sales order controller. */
@InjectMocks
private SalesOrderController salesOrderController;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(salesOrderController).build();
}

@Test
public void testReassignSalesOrder() throws Exception {
    ReassignSalesOrderRequest lSalesOrderUpdateRequest = new ReassignSalesOrderRequest();
    lSalesOrderUpdateRequest.setRedirectOption("Satellite");
    lSalesOrderUpdateRequest.setSatelliteId(200L);
    lSalesOrderUpdateRequest.setSalesOrderIds(Collections.singletonList(1L));
    when(salesOrderService.reassignSalesOrder(100L, lSalesOrderUpdateRequest)).thenReturn(new BaseResponse());
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mockMvc.perform(patch("/api/issuers/100/reassign-sales-orders")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(lSalesOrderUpdateRequest)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    verify(salesOrderService).reassignSalesOrder(100L, lSalesOrderUpdateRequest);
}
```

}

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:55)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:82)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:617)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:178)
at com.gide.csri.cui.controller.SalesOrderControllerTest.testReassignSalesOrder(SalesOrderControllerTest.java:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:79)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:85)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

so why i am getting this error what's wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
Be sure that your class **ReassignSalesOrderRequest**  has all setters, getters and constructor ( mostly the  no args constructor).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 easy ways to find out.

- Debug your test code and look at the response body and not just the status code. Or even assert on the body too.
- Set your log level to debug and surely your Spring application will also show the error for the incorrect client request.

Comment: Believe it or not, I had the same situation and the log level didn't help at all. Even breakpoints didn't fire, because the error was not in the controller code, but in my request DTO. It was missing the \@NoArgsConstructor and \@Setter as the other answer pointed out.